# É possível realizar a venda de uma postagem Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, pagamento-online, custom-post-types

Estou a desenvolver uma revista digital, com visualização flipbook, zoom e tudo mais.

Porém tenho a seguinte dúvida, atualmente eu tenho um `post_type` que se chama Revistas, onde eu monto minha revista e publico como um post normal. Porém, certas revistas serão pagas. É possível vender um post?

Tipo, a pessoa vai e acessa o link daquele post, se ele não estiver logado, ou estiver logado e não realizou o pagamento, ele veria uma página com a opção de compra da revista, ou a liberação da mesma. Após o pagamento confirmado a partir de algum *gateway* de pagamento o usuário já teria acesso ao post, mas só se estiver logado!

Answer (score 0):

Bom diaa, como não obtive a resposta aqui, continuei a minha busca e nem imaginava que minha pergunta seria tão simples... Acabei achando diversos pluguins de Membership. Onde a maioria tinha as opções de proteger certas areas da aplicação e liberar apos a compra de uma assinatura.

Obrigado `jbueno` por melhorar minha pergunta anteriormente!